# How to set the values selected in select2 list box in MVC application when i want edit the data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ListBox("RiskFactors", null, new { @class = "form-control select2" })

<script>
    $('#RiskFactors').select2({
           placeholder: 'Select Risk Factors',
           closeOnSelect: false
       });
</script>
```

Hi I hope I can communicate the information correctly and I apologize for the language errors

[image]

Comment: In edit page, you want selected value?

Comment: yes, i want show it in edit page

Comment: have you add "select2.js" and  jquery framework in you page?

Comment: the old selections have got through Model, i want show it

Comment: yes, i used select2

Comment: @Mohammad please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/1jnL3wgy/2/

Comment: @jishan siddique thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the working example here you need to replace this code with your functionality.

```js
var values = "1,3";
$('#example').val(values.split(','));
$('#example').select2().trigger('chnage');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha256-FdatTf20PQr/rWg+cAKfl6j4/IY3oohFAJ7gVC3M34E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-d/edyIFneUo3SvmaFnf96hRcVBcyaOy96iMkPez1kaU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">Youvalue</option>
  <option value="3">Yourvalue </option>
</select>
```